# Can hadoop take input from multiple directories and files

Tags: input, hadoop

As I set the fileinputFormat as hadoop input.
The `arg[0]+"/*/*/*"` said match no files.

what I want to is to read from multiple files as:

```
Directory1
---Directory11
   ---Directory111
        --f1.txt
        --f2.txt
---Directory12
Directory2
---Directory21
```

is it possible in Hadoop?
Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can take input from multiple directories and files by using the ***** operator.  Most likely it's because the "arg[0]" argument isn't correct and therefore it's not finding the files.

As an alternative, you can also use InputFormat.addInputPath or if you need separate formats or mappers the [MultipleInputs](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapred/lib/MultipleInputs.html) class can be used.

Example of basic adding a path

```
FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, myInputPath);
```

Here is an example of MultipleInputs

```
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputPath1, TextInputFormat.class, MyMapper.class);
MultipleInputs.addInputPath(job, inputPath2, TextInputFormat.class, MyOtherMapper.class);
```

This other question is also very similar and has good answers, [Hadoop to reduce from multiple input formats](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10213791/hadoop-to-reduce-from-multiple-input-formats).

Comment: So it'll read from the multiple folders within one folder and recursively the many files within each of the sub-folder??

Comment: I was mistaken, and updated my answer to reflect this.  I'm guessing your "arg[0]" is wrong.  where are you using that from? if its the command line you might need $arg[0], if it's from code you should use the multipleinputs approach

Comment: It's in my java code. I used FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(conf, new Path(args[0]); it's the args[0] and something after it that I should replace the multiple directories part?

Comment: can you check to make sure those files are there starting at your arg[0] direction.  hadoop hdfs -ls /my/path/to/files

Comment: yes, There're in my hadoop arg[0] direction. and.. my arg[0] path is:/user/XXX/hadoopin  and the root folder of these nested folders and files is emails. when I used the code arg[0] + "/*/*/*/" it showes /user/XXX/hadoopin/email/email11 and doesn't match any file...

Comment: `arg[0] + "/*/*/*/" ` needs to be `arg[0]+"/*/*/*", does that match any files? and I believe javax.mail can be used, but I don't really know

Comment: Thanks! Your solution is always so helpful!